# Embed Developer Tools for a WebView in Chrome Packaged Apps

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to open Developer Tools for a `<webview>` in Chrome Packaged Apps inside another `<webview>` using `chrome-devtools://` protocol?

Answer (score 0):

you can open dev tools by right-clicking on content inside webview and choosing inspect element. Unfortunately this works only for the unpacked packaged apps loaded from the file system. Right click is disabled in the app loaded from the Chrome Web store. I placed a question on this to Google engineers but did not get a response yet. Will update when I do.

Update: got an answer from Google: enable the flag "Enable debugging for packed apps" in about:flags. See this answer in [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583545/debugging-new-chrome-packaged-apps).

Comment: Your update sadly does not help. It enables the context menu for the app's window itself, but the webview is "opaque"

Comment: did you enable the flag in 'about:flags'? Unfortunately I do not work with webview in Chrome Apps anymore, switched to React Native development, so can not check if anything changed in Dev tools.

Comment: I did enable it. Otherwise the app's window menu would not appear.

Comment: However, you are explicitly _not_ answering OP's question, which is how to _embed_ Dev Tools and not how to simply open them.